# Help with defining binary relation image in ZFC

Tags: set-theory, relations

I need to define in ZFC the following things:

- image and domain of a binary relation ($\{ x \mid (x,y)\in f \}$ would be a definition of domain, but it is a class for which is for me is not quite clear why it is a set)
- f[X] for a binary relation $f$ and a set $X$

Please describe a more or less formal way to describe these things in ZFC.

Comment: Replacement is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many ways to encode ordered pairs into sets. But they all have one necessary key: you can "decode" the first element, and you can "decode" the second element.

In the standard Kuratowski way, $(x,y)=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$, and then $x$ is the unique element which is in both sets that appear in $(x,y)$; and $y$ is either equal to $x$, or it is the unique element of $\bigcup(x,y)$ which is not $x$.

Given a fixed way of encoding ordered pairs into sets, let $\pi_1(z,x)$ be the formula which takes in $z$ as an ordered pair and $x$, and returns true if and only if $x$ is the left coordinate of $z$. And let $\pi_2(z,y)$ be the similar formula for decoding the right coordinate.

So, given a set of ordered pairs, $f$ in your case:

1. $\operatorname{dom}(f)=\{x\mid\exists z\in f\ \exists y(\pi_1(z,x)\land\pi_2(z,y))\}$ is a set using the replacement axiom for $\exists y(\pi_1(z,x)\land\pi_2(z,y))$
2. $\operatorname{rng}(f)=\{y\mid\exists z\in f\ \exists x(\pi_1(z,x)\land\pi_2(z,y))\}$, is a set for similar reasons.
3. $f[X]=\{y\in\operatorname{rng}(f)\mid\exists x\in X\ (x,y)\in f\}$ is a set due to separation.

Answer (score 1):

The axiom of replacement!

For the domain of a relation $R$, for instance: to each element $p$ of $R$ we may, definably, associate its left coordinate $p_0$. Then, using replacement, we get the set of all left coordinates, i.e. the domain. (I'm assuming by "domain" you mean $\{x: \exists y ((x, y)\in R)\}.$)

Exercise: show that replacement is necessary. (Hint: $V_{\omega+\omega}$ is a model of every $ZFC$ axiom except replacement. . .)